# How do you convert a numpy.int64 number to a datetime object?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, finance

I am working with a pandas dataframe that has a column called "timestamp" that starts at 0 and then increases as if it is a datetime object. When I use type() on the objects in the Pandas series/column "timestamp", it says each datapoint is a numpy.int64. The data are at millisecond granularity; for example, the next number in the "timestamp" column after 0 is 768, or 768 milliseconds after midnight on the date the data is from. But this is where it gets annoying. After 59999 it jumps to 100000 and since it is just an 64-bit integer, I can't perform timedelta operations on this data. How do I add a new column that has this info but in a true numpy datetime object or, even better, just converts everything to milliseconds from midnight? For example, 1000000, or 10:00:000, would become 600000.

To give context, I want to create a series of dataframes with each dataframe containing X seconds of data. So ideally I would just parse through the data by the "timestamp" column and take out the rows from t to t plus (X*1000) milliseconds, but I can't do that currently because the data isn't in pure millisecond form. Here is a picture of what the data looks like:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H05mw.png)

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Could you provide us with a sample of your data that includes the referring issue? Thank you.

Comment: @Ehsan in what format? I included a picture but I assume you mean the actual file. I assumed pandas.read_csv() to read a csv. I’ll post a link to the file in a second!

Comment: *I used pandas.read_csv()

Comment: a link to file or a adding a printed section of your dataframe to your post would be good. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.algoseek.com/static/files/sample_data/futures_and_future_options/ESH5.Futures.FullDepth.20150128.csv.zip

Comment: Yes, your data seems to jump from 59881 to 100259, but your data have any requirement for occur in a fixed period (or a minimal period) of time? I ask that because your have an operation in [2] 464, and 2 milliseconds later you have 2 operations at the "same millisecond" ([3] 468 and [4] 468). Is this a normal behavior for your data?

Comment: Normally a row will have the same timestamp as others rows if both the “buy” and “sell” data were updated at the same millisecond, or, the exchange server had multiple updates within a few milliseconds but reports all of them as the same timestamp. On the exchange server the 2 actions at 468 milliseconds probably were separated by microsecond or even nanoseconds, but the data isn’t reported with that granularity. For better or worse, my infrastructure can’t get anywhere near <1ms latency so I just need to convert 468 (even if it appears in multiple rows) to a datetime object.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSV file doesn't have the day that the info was sample so you'll have to adapt the code to "*convert everything to milliseconds from midnight*" of the desired day.

```
dt = "2020-05-05 00:00:00.000000"
```

ESH5 Example **CSV file**

```
Timestamp, Ticker, Side, Flags, Depth, Level1, ...
[000] 000000000, ESH5, BUY, 0, 10, 2035.00000000 x 7 (6),...
[001] 000000000, ESH5, SELL, 0, 10, 2035.25000000 x 7 (6),...
[002] 000000464, ESH5, BUY, 0, 10, 2035.00000000 x 9 (7),...
[003] 000000468, ESH5, BUY, 0, 10, 2035.00000000 x 9 (7),..
...
...
[287] 235959340, ESH5, BUY, 0, 10, 1996.25000000 x 16 (9),... 
[288] 235959342, ESH5, BUY, 0, 10, 1996.25000000 x 16 (9),...
[289] 235959789, ESH5, SELL, 0, 10, 1996.50000000 x 17 (8),...
[290] 235959884, ESH5, SELL, 0, 10, 1996.50000000 x 17 (8),...
```

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

def fix_Timestamp(t):
    t = str("{:09d}".format(t))
    dt = "2020-05-05 {}:{}:{}.{}000".format(t[0:2], t[2:4], t[4:6], t[6:9])
    dt64 = np.datetime64(dt)
    ts = (dt64 - np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
    return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(df)

df['fixedTimestamp'] = df.Timestamp.apply(fix_Timestamp)

print(df['fixedTimestamp'])
```

Output from `df['fixedTimestamp']`

```
0     2020-05-05 00:00:00.000
1     2020-05-05 00:00:00.000
2     2020-05-05 00:00:00.464
3     2020-05-05 00:00:00.468
4     2020-05-05 00:00:00.468
                ...
286   2020-05-05 23:59:59.340
287   2020-05-05 23:59:59.340
288   2020-05-05 23:59:59.342
289   2020-05-05 23:59:59.789
290   2020-05-05 23:59:59.884
Name: fixedTimestamp, Length: 291, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This was my first ever post and I am blown away with how helpful this response was :) thank you for taking the time. I am a total noob so I learned a few things from your code :)

Comment: so I should have noticed this from your sample print out, but unfortunately this code doesn't work. This entire csv is the data for one day, so the last fixedTimestamp should also be some time on 2020-05-05. The "timestamp" value of very last row for the DataFrame imported from the csv is 235959884. This is not 235959884 milliseconds after midnight, but rather, 23:59:59:884 in the hh:mm:ss:ms format but without the colons. Does this help you understand my problem better?